# SilverStripe gridField Entries not visible for normal backend user

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have two user groups **Administrator** and **Inhaltsautoren**

My LandingPage has a Tab **Teaser** with a **gridField**. The normal user can not see the entries and i dont know why?

I cant find something for setting the permissions for Inhaltsautoren. Has someone an idea why there are no entries in the gridField?

Teaser.php

```
<?php 

class Teaser extends DataObject {

private static $db = array (
    'Title' => 'Varchar',
    'Description' => 'HTMLText'
);

private static $has_one = array (
    'Photo' => 'Image',
    'Link' => 'Link'
);

private static $many_many = array(
    'Tags' => 'Tag'
);

private static $summary_fields = array (
    'GridThumbnail' => '',
    'Title' => 'Titel',
    'Description' => 'Beschreibung'
);

public function getGridThumbnail() {
    if($this->Photo()->exists()) {
        return $this->Photo()->SetWidth(100);
    }

    return "(no image)";
}

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        TextField::create('Title'),
        $tags = TagField::create('Tags','Tags',Tag::get(),$this->Tags()),
        HTMLEditorField::create('Description', 'Beschreibung'),
        LinkField::create('LinkID', 'Weiterleitung'),
        $uploader = UploadField::create('Photo')
    );

    $tags->setShouldLazyLoad(true); // tags should be lazy loaded
    $tags->setCanCreate(true);      // new tag DataObjects can be created

    $uploader->setFolderName('teaser');
    $uploader->getValidator()->setAllowedExtensions(array('png','jpeg','jpg'));

    return $fields;
}
}
```

and my LadingPage.php

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Teaser', $gridField = GridField::create(
    'Teasers',
    'Landing Page Teaser',
    $this->Teasers(),
    GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
));


$gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType("GridFieldDataColumns")->setFieldCasting(array("Description"=>"HTMLText->BigSummary"));
```

Comment: Have a look at the canView() canEdit() canCreate() and canEdit() functions. You can find them in the api documentation. They controll who can see your data and so on. You need to put them into your dataobject. It has nothing to do with the gridfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [canView()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-DataObject.html#_canView) on your dataobject and check inside this function if your user is allowed to see this object or not.

```
  public function canView($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('ADMIN', 'any');
  }
```